# Angular controller is not working with PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

I can't get my controller to work with PHP MySQLi.

This is the body of my html document:

```
<body class="nav-is-fixed" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productsCtrl">

<div id="cd-search" class="cd-search">
    <form>
        <input type="search" ng-model="simpleFilter" placeholder="Pretraga ...">
    </form>
</div>

    <!-- your content here -->    
    <div class="container" >        

        <section class="grid-wrap"> 

            <ul class="grid" id="grid"> 

                <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:simpleFilter">  
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/dummy.jpg" alt="dummy"><h3>{{ product.naziv }}</h3></a>
                </li> 

            </ul>
        </section>
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <!-- your content here -->    


<!-- menu -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> 
<!-- menu -->

<!-- include angular js -->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- my angular js codes will be here -->
<script src="js/angular/angular_controller.js"></script>     
<!-- my angular js codes will be here -->
```

This is a version of a controller that works, nothing fancy:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("productsCtrl",function($scope,$http){

        $scope.products = [
                            {naziv:'Livanjski sir'},
                            {naziv:'Livanjac'},
                            {naziv:'Trapist'},
                            {naziv:'Sunce'},
                            {naziv:'Koziji sir'},
                            {naziv:'Ovčiji sir'},
                            {naziv:'Dalmatinski sir'},
                            {naziv:'Delminium veliki kolut'},
                            {naziv:'Svježi sir'},
                            {naziv:'Delmato'},
                            {naziv:'Edamer'},
                            {naziv:'Gouda'},
                            {naziv:'Domaca livada'},
                            {naziv:'Domaci bijeli sir'},
                            {naziv:'Maslac'},       
                        ];  

    });
```

But when I try to do this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  //app.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    app.controller("productsCtrl",function($scope,$http){

        getProducts(); // Load all available productsks 

        function getProducts()
        {  
            $http.post("produkti.php").success(function(data)
                {
                    $scope.products = data;
                }
            );
        };      

    });
```

This is the produkti.php document:

```
 <?php

// Including database connections
require_once '../resources/config.php';

    $query="select NAZIV from produkti";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    $arr = array();
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arr[] = $row;  
        }
    }

    # JSON-encode the response
    echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Just can't get it to work and can't find the error in my code.

Comment: Nevermind guys,i figured it out. When i created my table, i had balkan characters in my column, and my encoding wasn't set to utf-8. So,,because of that,json_encode($arr); wasn't working right. Once i fixed that, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys,i figured it out. When i created my table, i had balkan characters in my column, and my encoding wasn't set to utf-8. So,,because of that,json_encode($arr); wasn't working right. Once i fixed that, it worked :)